# Background color change: addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

my eventListener doesn't appear to be working.

I have got the button in the middle and the background color to red but when I try to click the button to change background color it wont work.

Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Change Background Color</title>
    <script src="first.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stuff.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn" id="btn">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
    const colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const randomNumber = 2;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
    color.textContent = colors[randomNumber];
}
);
```

CSS:

```
    button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: `const randomNumber = 2;` Doesn't seem too random

Answer (score 2):

So, there are a couple things.

You don't have an element in the HTML with a class of 'color'.

Second is that your randomNumber isn't really random.  I'm sure that you're on your way to implement that though.  However, I'll just include my version of how to randomize the color in the snippet below.

Here's a fixed up version:

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');

// This function returns a random number from min to min + range
const getRandomNumber = (min, range) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * range + min)
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const randomNumber = getRandomNumber(0, colors.length);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
  color.textContent = colors[randomNumber];
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

.color {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btn">Click Me</button>

<div class="color">red</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, you don't have any class by the name of `.color` in your HTML, Also your `const randomNumber = 2;` doesn't look too random.  So here, I fixed both for you by adding a simple div with class `color` to it. as well as a simple math function to give you a random integer between 0 and 3 to cover all your colors.  Take a look.

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
  color.textContent = colors[randomNumber];
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btn">Click Me</button>
<div class="color">
Color name will show here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have no element with the selector class of `.color` in your HTML, therefor your `color.textContent` will return `null`.
2. You have no code that parses a random value out of your array. You're simply calling the third index of your arrays value `const randomNumber = 2;` this will always give you blue as it is the third value `0 => green, 1 => red, 2 => blue`

The following should be what you are looking for...

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {          
  let random = colors[~~(Math.random()*colors.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = random;
  color.textContent = random;
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
</div>
<button class="btn" id="btn">Click Me</button>
```